# "Ich werd nicht mehr" - what is the missing part?

Tags: idiom, colloquial

A German speaker who is surprised or astonished might say something like:

> Ich glaub, ich werd nicht mehr!

But, *werd nicht mehr* what? Werd nicht mehr aufhören, mich zu wundern? Werd nicht mehr ruhig?

Is this known?

Comment: What did your search reveal about this idiom?

Comment: *werden* is an auxiliary used to construct future tense as well as passive voice, but it is also a full verb meaning *to become* (transitive) or simply *to come into existence* (intransitive). By gut feeling, I always understood the phrase as the latter. But cf. also "Das wird nichts mehr" = "This will not become anything any more" = "We will not manage to complete our plan"

Comment: I don't think there is an ellipsis, *werden* is used as a full verb here.

Comment: My speculative theory would be that this started as a humoristic (at the time) combination of two non-fitting known exclamations, e.g. "ich glaub, ich werd verrückt" und "ich glaub's nicht mehr" or something like that, Comparable to "das schlägt dem Fass die Krone ins Gesicht!". Would be interesting if anything substantial is known about how this originated.

Comment: To explain why I have doubts about the "werden as full verb" explanation: we normally just don't use "werden" as a full intransitive verb with grown-up persons as a subject. The sentence "Ich werde." has no meaning on its own for a person saying it.

Comment: My speculation would be it comes from "mit etwas fertig werden" / "zurecht kommen", i.e. "Ich glaube ich werd [damit] nicht mehr [fertig]"

Comment: I guess, _werden_ is a full verb here, but it is still an ellipsis.

Comment: @infinitezero: "Ich werd nicht mehr" für "ich werd nicht mehr fertig" hätte auf jeden Fall einen sehr schönen Selbstbezug. :-)

Comment: Here's an [example](https://www.motor-talk.de/forum/ich-glaub-ich-werd-nicht-mehr-rost-t2161983.html) for y'all, the phrase is used twice in this post (once in its title): "Ich glaub ich werd nicht mehr!!! Rost!!!" and then, further down, "Als ich den Rost gesehn habe dachte ich, ich werd nicht mehr."  Context is displeasure at finding rust on his 14-year-old Mercedes 190D (the warranty running out after 8).

Comment: Does anyone at least know how old the idiom is? My theory, if anyone cares, is it's a shortened version of something like *Ich glaube es nicht und werde es auch nicht mehr glauben.* -- "I don't believe it and I never will." But one can speculate all day long and not accomplish anything, some hard evidence is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Umgangssprache sollte man nicht gleich auf die Goldwaage legen, denn so mancher Spruch ist aus reinem Spass entstanden. Ich selbst moechte den angefuehrten Spruch noch ergaenzen zu: Ich werd' nicht mehr normal, was durch die anderen Versionen schon abgedeckt wurde und keiner weiteren Erklaerung bedarf. Als Muttersprachler verstehe ich den Spruch sofort.
Dabei denke ich an den anderen Spruch "Ich geh' kaputt", der vor einigen Jahrzehnten sehr plötzlich auftauchte, gar keinen echten Sinn ergibt und auch schon wieder verschwunden ist. So geht's zu in der Umgangssprache !

Answer (score -2):

This is meant as "**Ich werd**e darüber **nicht mehr** fertig", respectively "**Ich werd**e davon **nicht mehr** normal" or similar, which means "Ich erhole mich gar nicht mehr davon". Literally as "I won't be (the same as before)".

A related thing is "etwas werden" (engl. "to become") which fits here as well, and they all together makes it a cool phrase one can interpret in different ways but always has the same meaning.

---

Supplement: "**Werden**" also has the meaning of "gedeihen (to prosper), gelingen (to succeed)", which was mainly meant here. That form of "werden" does not need an object. All listed possibilities from above fit as synonyms (that one cannot find back to a proper state). I cannot give you an ethymological prove but all searched internet disscussions mainly agree with it, like e.g. [here](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idForum=4&idThread=966815&lp=ende&lang=de). It is also very obvious and therefore self-explaining. You say the expression in a moment of surprise, and show this way how it knocks you out.

dict.cc lists 3 translations <sup>([2](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Ich%20dachte%2C%20ich%20werd%20nicht%20mehr))</sup>:

- I don't believe it!
- Well, I never (did)! [coll.]
- You could have knocked me down with a feather. [coll.]

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Why not? He just wants to know what the missing part is and what it means, and this is what I've replied.

Comment: You do not tell, what the missing part is. The OP would like to know what the X is in "Ich werd nicht mehr X". You just don't say this.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Nun noch klarer durch fettgedruckte Schrift und weitere Alternativergänzung.

Comment: @äüö: Auf welchen Quellen oder Beobachtungen beruht die Aussage? Und welche der zwei bis drei genannten Aussagen trifft wann genau zu - ist das kontextabhängig, oder sind sie alle gleichbedeutend? Ich habe den Eindruck, die Antwort listet nur verschiedene Möglichkeiten auf, um den Satz prinzipiell passend zu vervollständigen, ohne darauf einzugehen, aus welchen dieser Möglichkeiten (wenn überhaupt) sich die gebräuchliche Formulierung ursprünglich ableitet.

Comment: What's _darüber fertig werden_ supposed to mean? I never heard a phrase like that.

Comment: @Lykanion: "drüber fertig werden" => "get over it"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das sind Dinge, die man als Muttersprachler kennt/einschätzen kann. Die Aussagen sind grundsätzlich alle gleichbedeutend. Die Phrase lässt die Vervollständigung bewusst offen - das ist ja gerade das schöne daran.

Comment: Die Antworten passen syntaktisch nicht, auch wenn sie fett geschrieben sind  :) Deine Begründung ist reine Spekulation, die mich nicht überzeugt. Du sagst, was es *sein könnte*, es geht aber darum, was es *ist*. Auch die Fragen von O.R. Mapper sind nicht beantwortet. Daher gebe ich jetzt hier -1.

Comment: Ich habe die Antwort jetzt nochmal erweitert.